# How to register a Delegator Factory for a Hydrator in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, factory, zend-framework-mvc

[Delegator Factories](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/zend-framework-2-delegator-factories-explained/) in Zend Framework 2 are a powerful tool to hook into the creating of standard ZF objects and change or even completely replcae them by custom ones.

I want to create a Delegator Factory for a Hydrator, in order to attach some Hydrator Strategies to it. But it's not working yet...

**`module.config.php`**

```
return array(
    ...
    'service_manager' => array(
        ...
        'invokables' => array(
            ...
            'AuthenticationAdapterDelegatorFactory' => 'Foo\\MvcAuth\\Factory\\AuthenticationAdapterDelegatorFactory', // <-- it works
            'DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory' => 'Bar\\Model\\Entity\\Hydrator\\DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory', // <-- it doesn't
        ),
        'delegators' => array(
            'ZF\\MvcAuth\\Authentication\\DefaultAuthenticationListener' => array( // <-- it works
                0 => 'AuthenticationAdapterDelegatorFactory',
            ),
            'DoctrineModule\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\DoctrineObject' => array( // <-- it doesn't
                0 => 'DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory'
            )
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

Since hydrators are actually provided by the `HydratorPluginManager`, I've also tried it this way:

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        ...
        'invokables' => array(
            ...
            'DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory' => 'Bar\\Model\\Entity\\Hydrator\\DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory',
        ),
        'delegators' => array(
            ...
            'DoctrineModule\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\DoctrineObject' => array( // <-- it doesn't
                0 => 'DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory'
            )
        ),
    ),
    'hydrator_manager' => array(
        'delegators' => array(
            'DoctrineModule\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\DoctrineObject' => array(
                0 => 'DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory'
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

So what is going wrong here and how can I register a Delegator Factory for a Hydrator in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are totally right you have to register the delegators for your hydrator classes inside the `HydratorPluginManager`. The problem lies in the key name in your `module.config.php`.

The key to use is `hydrators` and not like you have `hydrator_manager`:

```
'hydrators' => array(
    'delegators' => array(
        //...your delegators config...
    )
),
```

I personally think the naming of keys in the ZF2 config arrays is very inconsistent and confusing. Keep this in mind if you have similar problems like this again.

Check also [this page from Rob Allen as a reference](http://akrabat.com/zendservicemanager-configuration-keys/) for all other service manager configuration keys.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, the naming is very strange. In my service I  retrieve the `HydratorManager` from the `ServiceManager` with `$this->serviceManager->get('hydratormanager')` (optionally with or without underscore).

Comment: The last thing I'm still not getting. I've tried this following the scheme of my `AuthenticationAdapterDelegatorFactory`: `'hydrators' => [
    'delegators' => ['...\\DoctrineObject' => [0 => 'MyDelegatorKey']],
    'invocables' => ['MyDelegatorKey' => [0 => 'Bar\\Model\\Entity\\Hydrator\\DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory]],
]`. But it didn't work. the `DoctrineObjectHydratorDelegatorFactory` cannot be found.

Comment: @automatix You have a typo: `invocables` should be `invokables` :)

Comment: Oh, you are right -- it was a typo. :) But I made it only here in the comment. The code is correct. But anyway -- it doesn't work. The inkables defined within the `hydrators` can only be hydrators. And if I set it unter `servide_manager.invokables`, it cannot be found.

Comment: Do you know, where there is a way to get working with a separate invokable's configuration and passing the key in the `delegators` config array?

Comment: @automatix Registering a `Factory` under key `invokables` seems not right in the first place. Maybe you should look into some ZF2 delegator examples and check how it is commonly configured before you continue. I don't have much experience with delegators, but your config structure seems incorrect.

Comment: My logic is: A `DelegatorFactory` don't need a "meta-factory" to be instantiated, so it is an invokable and should be defined under the key `invokables`. Anyway, `factory` doesn't work.  I haven't found any examples in the ZF2 code. Well, the most important thing is, that it works. The option to define the delegator class separately is "only" nice to have. Thank you very much once again for your help!

Comment: @automatix Maybe [this example](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/zend-framework-2-delegator-factories-explained/) from Ocramius can be of help.

Comment: Yes, I know this article -- and it's really a greate one, since it explains the Delegator Factories short and clearly and makes it very easy to use. But Marco says nothing about the creating a DF. So, I think there is no best practice for this. But as I already said, following the common logic, the `invokalbes` key should be used. The `ServiceManager` can instantiate a DF without any params. The problem in my case with a `Hydrator` is, that in the context of the `HydratorPluginManager` `invocables` have to be `Hydrator`s.

Comment: Btw. I've just discovered [`DelegatingHydrator`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/blob/master/src/Hydrator/DelegatingHydrator.php). It doesn't resolve my problem, but seems to be a nice alternative solution.